# markdown-it can not escape ampersand character

Tags: javascript, ampersand, markdown-it

I have tried to parse HTML content using [Markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) with following lines in head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/11.0.1/markdown-it.min.js "></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var mdit = window.markdownit();
 
  mdit.set({
    highlight: function (str, lang) {
      if (lang && hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
        try {
          var code = '<pre class="hljs"><code>'
            + hljs.highlight(lang, str, true).value
            + '</code></pre>';
          return code;
        } catch (__) {}
      }
    }
  });
  
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('markdown');
  for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    var content = div[i].innerHTML;
    var code = document.getElementsByClassName('markdown')[i];
    code.innerHTML = mdit.render(content);
  }
}
</script>
```

and these lines in body section

````
## C++
```cpp
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  cout << i << endl;
}
````

which produces

### C++

```
for(var i = 0; i &lt; 10; i++) {
  cout &lt;&lt; i &lt;&lt; endl;
}
```

It seems that `render()` function from `markdownit()` can not escape the handle `&` character. I guess that `<` is translated to `&lt;` but later the `&` is translated to `&amp;`, so it becomes `&amp;t;` and rendered as `&lt;` instead of `<` in the final result.

I have found the workaround with

```
code.innerHTML = mdit.render(content).replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
```

but hope can still find the better answer by using setting of Markdown-it.

Comment: You will probably get a better response by asking here https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it/issues